# Using an SQLite return as a password field within Bcrypt (Python)

Tags: python, sqlite, bcrypt

I want to check if the input password is the same as that stored in the database but when I use `bcrypt.checkpw()` it returns an error saying that it expects a string or byte because the SQL query returns a tuple. I can't find a way to convert the database response to a byte from a tuple to make it compatible.

```
sql = ''' SELECT password FROM user_data WHERE username=? '''

username = input('Input username: ')
password = bytes(input('Input Password: '), encoding='utf-8')

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(sql, (username,))
rows = cur.fetchall()

for row in rows:

    if bcrypt.checkpw(password, row):
        details = (user_id, username, password)
        print('logged in')

        return details

        break
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply adding row[0] within the function solves the problem as it returns the first (and only) value inside the tuple.

**Treat it like a list** in other words

[Extracting the a value from a tuple when the other values are unused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5122041/extracting-the-a-value-from-a-tuple-when-the-other-values-are-unused/5122098)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Link-only answers are bad! You should summarize the linked page in your answer here so your answer doesn't become 
useless in case of [link-rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).
[Why is linking bad?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/7515/174780)
| 
[Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/174780) 
| 
[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/174780)

Comment: If this question is an exact duplicate, please close it as a duplicate instead of adding answers here.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi it is not a duplicate it just is solvable with an answer to another question, I'm guessing that why you have a problem with it